# Populating globalized (Globalize2) DB using db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, seed, populate, globalize2

I,m using Globalize2. I'd like to populate DB with db:seed for different locales: en, de and ru. Is there a better solution then:

```
categories = [{ :en => 'Health & Beauty', :ru => 'Красота и здоровье', :de => 'Beauty & Gesundheit'},
              { :en => 'Baby', :ru => 'Детские товары', :de => 'Baby' }]

categories.each_index do |i|
  I18n.locale = 'en'
  Category.create(:name => categories[i][:en])
  I18n.locale = 'ru'
  cat = Category.find(:last)
  cat.name = categories[i][:ru]
  cat.save
  I18n.locale = 'de'
  cat.name = categories[i][:de] 
  cat.save
end
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Globalize2 version 0.2.0 released, we can use a little simplier code:

```
categories = [{ :en => 'Health & Beauty', :ru => 'Красота и здоровье', :de => 'Beauty & Gesundheit'},
              { :en => 'Baby', :ru => 'Детские товары', :de => 'Baby' }]

categories.each_index do |i|
  I18n.locale = 'en'
  cat = Category.new :name => categories[i][:en]
  I18n.locale = 'ru'
  cat.name = categories[i][:ru]
  I18n.locale = 'de'
  cat.name = categories[i][:de]
  cat.save
end
```